# NSTimer If Statement Not Running Properly

Tags: xcode, cocoa, if-statement, nstimer

I want a button "getcoins" to set off a timer then trigger an if statement so that if the value of "_currentField" //text field is greater than or equal to 1000 run the lines of code I wrote. If its anything else then run the other lines of code. Every time I run this application and try and perform the action it runs the debugger and highlights the first line of the if statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (IBAction)getcoins:(id)sender {
        [_progIndicator startAnimation:(id)sender];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(onTimer:)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];

}
// Timer for get coins
- (void)onTimer:(NSTimer*)aTimer {

    if ([_currentField.stringValue integerValue] >= 1000)

    {
        [_congrats orderFront:(id)self];
        [_progIndicator stopAnimation:(id)self];
    }

    else { 
        [_errormsg orderFront:(id)self];
        [_progIndicator stopAnimation:(id)self];

        }

    }
```

Comment: Since you are only doing a single invocation it would be equivalent to use the `NSObject` method `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.  Also, the `onTimer:` method in your code does not need an `IBAction` tag and your calls do not need to include casts like `(id)self`.

Comment: You need to change `selector:@selector(onTimer)` to `selector:@selector(onTimer:)` (with colon), otherwise it names a different method.

Comment: I forgot to edit that in my question! Sorry about that. I also edited the last part of the question with important info.

Comment: By "it runs the debugger" do you mean it crashes there?  That could happen if `_currentField.stringValue` is `nil` (because there would be no way to return an `integerValue` from nothing).

Comment: I enter in a value of 1000 and it crashes. It basically crashes no matter what value I enter.

Comment: OK.  I suspect at this point the problem is *not* related to the timer (which seems to work fine); there is an issue in the setup of your field.  Please indicate (or maybe post a new question) what type `_currentField` is, how you initialize its value, how it may be bound in a XIB file, etc.  I suppose it could also be a threading issue if the timer was somehow not run on the main thread.

Comment: If this helps at all, this is what it looks like when it crashes http://picturepush.com/public/8736518

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the problem has been fixed. It was just a breakpoint. I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
- (IBAction)getcoins:(id)sender {
    [_progIndicator startAnimation:(id)sender];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(onTimer)
                                   userInfo:_nil
                                    repeats:YES];

}
// Timer for get coins
- (void)onTimer:(NSTimer*)aTimer {

    if ([_currentField.stringValue integerValue] >= 1000)

    {
        [_congrats orderFront:self];
        [_progIndicator stopAnimation:self];
    }

    else { 
        [_errormsg orderFront:self];
        [_progIndicator stopAnimation:self];

        }

    }
```

Comment: This didn't change the result. After performing the action get coins, it opens up the debugger and highlights the first line of the if statement.

Comment: There is no msg it just gets highlighted in green like so http://picturepush.com/public/8736518

Comment: That isn't a crash, it's just a [breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/060-Debug_Your_App/debug_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW38)! The breakpoint tells Xcode to stop there. Press the play-pause button (right above "Auto") to continue.

Comment: @Johnny compiler stops at breakpoint You can disable it at the top, pushing "Activate breakpoint" button or grabbing left arrow and dragging out of Your project to destroy it.